# Getting an author's role in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i'm working on my first WP site and need to display an author's role next to their post. Something like "Jimmy | Administrator". Looking at the author metadata available: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta doesn't give me a way to access that. I'm sure there's a quick easy way to do this and i just don't know it!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Place this in your functions.php file:

```
function get_author_role()
{
    global $authordata;

    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

    return $author_role;
}
```

Then call this within your Wordpress Loop. So:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo get_the_author().' | '.get_author_role();
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

...will print: 'Jimmy | Administrator'

**COMPLETE ANSWER:** The User Object itself actually stores roles, and other kinds of useful information. If you want more of a general function to retrieve the role of any given user, simply pass in the ID of the user you want to target with this function:

```
function get_user_role($id)
{
    $user = new WP_User($id);
    return array_shift($user->roles);
}
```

And if you want to grab the author of a given post, call it like so:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $aid = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    echo get_the_author().' | '.get_user_role($aid);
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

**RESPONSE TO LAST COMMENT:**

If you need to grab data outside of the Wordpress Loop (which I imagine you're trying to do on an Archive and Author page), you can use the function from my Complete answer like so:

```
global $post;
$aid = $post->post_author;
echo get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $aid).' | '.get_user_role($aid);
```

That will output the information you want in your "user | role" format.

Comment: IT works fine in between loop but if I am adding on archive page or author page its giving me warning: `Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in` Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: @pixelngrain View my latest update for the answer you need. That should allow you to grab the information you need outside of the loop.

Comment: Bear in mind, you can use the post_author property from within the loop on your archive pages as well.