# Display Author role in archive or author page

Tags: wordpress, role, author

I want to display author role on archive and author page outside loop I found this code and it works fine within the loop
[Getting an author's role in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489214/getting-an-authors-role-in-wordpress/10489289#10489289)

But when I am adding this to archive and author page its giving me warning message called

```
Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These examples are using the function I gave in my **COMPLETE ANSWER** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489214/getting-an-authors-role-in-wordpress/10489289#10489289). In your functions.php file:

```
function get_user_role($id)
{
    $user = new WP_User($id);
    return array_shift($user->roles);
}
```

In your archive page:

```
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $aid = $post->post_author;
    echo get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $aid).' | '.get_user_role($aid);
endwhile;endif;
```

As for your author template, the [Wordpress Codex on Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) has a lot of useful information. You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
echo $curauth->user_nicename.' | '.get_user_role($curauth->ID);
?>
```

Comment: Cool! I have tested on different template and I believe its working fine. Let me check in my template and get back to you.. Thanks a lot